# hide/visible checkbox when radio button select and get the value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a hidden check box and show it after select the radio button

I want the check boxes hidden. and visible only if I select the radio button.
and last thing I want to get the values of them

this is the code:

```js
function apparition() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<div style="align-content: left;">
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-1">
                <input type="radio" id="option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Sur dalle - Pose à la française" checked>
                <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur dalle - Pose à la française</span>
              </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-2">
                <input type="radio" id="option-2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Contre dalle - Pose à l'anglaise" >
                <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre dalle - Pose à l'anglaise</span>
              </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-3">
                <input type="radio" id="option-3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Sur acrotère - pose à la Française" onClick="apparition()">
                <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur acrotère - pose à la Française</span>
              </label>
</div>
<p id="test" style="position: absolute;
margin-left: 10%; display:none;">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Passage devant dalle</span>
  </label>
</p>
```

and this is the screen capture :

[image]

Comment: Show when selecting which radio? You just need an eventListener on the radio and toggle a class or use a ternary to set style.display

Comment: thanks for the avdices. i success in checkbox apprear now i want to hide it when the radio not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

I delegate the click to the container (I gave it an ID)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("radioContainer").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = document.getElementById("option-3").checked ? "inline" : "none";
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="align-content: left;" id="radioContainer">
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-1">
    <input type="radio" id="option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Sur dalle - Pose à la française" checked />
      <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur dalle - Pose à la française</span>
    </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-2">
    <input type="radio" id="option-2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Contre dalle - Pose à l'anglaise" />
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Contre dalle - Pose à l'anglaise</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-3">
    <input type="radio" id="option-3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="Sur acrotère - pose à la Française" />
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Sur acrotère - pose à la Française</span>
  </label>
</div>
<p id="test">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Passage devant dalle</span>
  </label>
</p>
```